# Howto resolve this error :- InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm relatively new to neural networks and trying to train a music genre classification model using tensorflow.
Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andradaolteanu/gtzan-dataset-music-genre-classification

```
import librosa , librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import math
import os
```

```
DATASET_PATH ='/content/drive/MyDrive/DNN'
SAMPLE_RATE = 22050
DURATION = 30
SAMPLES_PER_TRACK = SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION #so that is the number of amplitude value to represent each file.wav
```

```
def save_mfcc(dataset_path  , n_mfcc = 13 , n_fft = 2048 , hop_length = 512 , num_segments = 5):
    data = {
        'mapping' :[] ,
        'mfcc' :[] ,
        'labels' : []
    }
    num_sample_per_segment = int(SAMPLES_PER_TRACK / num_segments) #so here every 30 second we would split then into 5 segments
    expected_num_mfcc_vector_per_segment = math.ceil(num_sample_per_segment / hop_length)
    print(f'{expected_num_mfcc_vector_per_segment} that is the length of the sequence')
    
    
    for i , (dirpath , dirnames , filenames) in enumerate(os.walk(dataset_path)):
        
        
        if dirpath != dataset_path:
            semantic_label = dirpath.split('/')[-1]
            data['mapping'].append(semantic_label)
            for file in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath , file)
                try :
                    signal , sr = librosa.load(file_path , sr = SAMPLE_RATE)
                    for s in range(num_segments):
                        start_sample = num_sample_per_segment * s
                        finish_sample = start_sample + num_sample_per_segment
                        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y = signal[start_sample:finish_sample] , sr = SAMPLE_RATE , 
                                                   n_mfcc=13 , n_fft = n_fft , hop_length = hop_length)
                        mfcc = mfcc.T # as we have the data (sequence number , number of features)
                        if len(mfcc) == expected_num_mfcc_vector_per_segment:
                            data['mfcc'].append(mfcc.tolist())
                            data['labels'].append(i-1)
                except:
                    pass
                        
            print(f"{dirpath.split('/')[-1]} is loaded successfully")
                        
    return data
```

```
data_dict = save_mfcc(DATASET_PATH  , num_segments=10)
```

```
data = np.array(data_dict['mfcc'])
label = np.array(data_dict['labels']).reshape(-1 , 1)
```

```
data.shape
label.shape
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test =train_test_split(data , label  ,test_size=0.2 ,shuffle= True)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid =train_test_split(X_train_val , y_train_val  ,test_size=0.2)
```

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    
    keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 13]),
    keras.layers.LayerNormalization(),
    keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.LayerNormalization(),
    keras.layers.LSTM(32),
    keras.layers.Dense(10 ,  activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(loss ='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam() , metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

```
model.fit(X_train , y_train ,validation_data=(X_valid , y_valid) , epochs=30 , batch_size=8)
```

And the error i got is:

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1cdbbd4440db> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train , y_train ,validation_data=(X_valid , y_valid) , epochs=30 , batch_size=8)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 687, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 821, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 782, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-24-1cdbbd4440db>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
      model.fit(X_train , y_train ,validation_data=(X_valid , y_valid) , epochs=30 , batch_size=8)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2078, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5660, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 12 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 3 6 9 7 4 7 11 12
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_27886]
```

I tried changing the code by surfing through some of stack overflow, but somehow was not able to execute that particular block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Meh, you need to read more. It clearly says this

> Received a label value of 12 which is outside the valid range of [0,
> 10).  Label values: 3 6 9 7 4 7 11 12

So basically your label input must have preprocessed wrong. Just print the unique values of your labels to confirm it.
You need to correct you label preprocessing to map it into [0,10)